# Bash while loop echo content of file as a drop down menu form

Tags: html, bash, loops

I have a file which contains following content. I want to be able to write a while loop and echo HTML form.

```
10.101.0.169
10.101.0.171
10.101.0.175
10.101.0.177
10.101.0.179
10.101.0.181
10.101.0.185
10.101.0.193
```

I want some thing like this.

```
while (file1 has entries)
{ echo "option value=IP address1" }
end
```

The goal is to publish a HTML form which users can use to select the IP address from drop down menu and click submit and parameters will be passed to a CGI script for further processing.

I am sure someone expert should be able to help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work in bash way.

```
while read line
    echo "option value=$line"
done < file_name
```

If you want it to be in HTML, could be like

```
echo "<select name=IP>"
while read line
    echo "<option value=$line>$line</option>"
done < file_name
echo "</select>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
#! /bin/bash
{
    echo '<select name="ip">'
    sed -e 's|.*|  <option value="&">&</option>|' file
    echo '</select>'
} > out.html
```